# Spresense SDKによるPWM出力周波数の下限について

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSE SDKでのPWM生成に関する質問です。

現在、examples/pwmを試しているのですが、PWMの最低周波数(動作周波数xカウンタ最大値?)で悩んでいます。50Hz周期のサーボモータを接続しようとしたところioctlでエラーとなってしまいました。125HzのPWMは正常に生成できました。

本内容に関する、SPRESENSEの仕様書やコード等、ご存知の方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

```
nsh> pwm -p /dev/pwm0 -f 125
pwm_main: starting output with frequency: 125 duty: 00008000
pwm_main: stopping output
nsh> pwm -p /dev/pwm0 -f 50
pwm_main: starting output with frequency: 50 duty: 00008000
pwm_main: ioctl(PWMIOC_START) failed: 22
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

お世話になっております。自己解決しました、ありがとうございます。

下記のifに捕まっていました。cxd56_get_pwm_baseclock(デフォルトではSCUと同じRCOSC)を基準として、16bit幅のカウンタを利用するため、最低125Hzということですね。理解しました。

- ~/spresense/sdk/bsp/src/cxd56_pwm.c

  ```c
  static int convert_freq2period(...)
  {
    ...
    pwmfreq = cxd56_get_pwm_baseclock();
    ...
    if ((freq > ((pwmfreq + 1) >> 1)) || (freq < (pwmfreq >> 16)))
      {
        pwmerr("Frequency out of range. %d [Effective range:%d - %d]\n",
                  freq, pwmfreq >> 16, (pwmfreq + 1) >> 1);
        return -1;
  ```

今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

PWM出力周波数の下限についてですが、先週リリース致しました、
SDK v1.5.1において1Hzからに対応いたしました。
詳細については、[PWM 周波数とデューティー比について](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_pwm_%E5%91%A8%E6%B3%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A8%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E6%AF%94%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)をご参照ください。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム